# product of m x n matrix with n x m matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to prove that product of  $\mathbb{m x n}$ matrix with $\mathbb{n x m}$ matrix is not invertible given $\mathbb{m >n}$.

For the case of $\mathbb{2 x 1}$ and $\mathbb{1 x 2}$ matrix, it is clear; since for the product matrix A; $\mathbb{AX=0}$ has non trivial solutions. (both the resulting equations turn out to be same after cancellation of common factors.

How to go about proving it for the general case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A$ be $m\times n$, and let $B$ be $n\times m$. Let $C=AB$. $C$ is $m\times m$, so it’s invertible if and only if its rank is $m$, i.e., if and only if the map

$$T_C:\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^m:x\mapsto Cx$$

is a surjection. (In possibly more elementary terms that’s saying that the column space of $C$ is all of $\Bbb R^m$.) But $T_C=T_A\circ T_B$, where

$$T_A:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m:x\mapsto Ax$$

and $$T_B:\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n:x\mapsto Bx\;.$$ That is, $T_C$ can be decomposed as

$$\Bbb R^m\overset{T_B}\longrightarrow\Bbb R^n\overset{T_A}\longrightarrow\Bbb R^m\;.$$

If $T_C$ is a surjection, $T_A$ must also be a surjection, and that’s impossible: the range of $T_A$ is the column space of $A$ and therefore has dimension at most $n$, and $n<m$.

Comment: Thanks! it does make sense that the product matrix C must have a rank of m to be invertible which is not possible since rank of product < min(rank of A and rank of B) = n <m . Seeing the matrices as operators helped understand the concept better. But, just making sure, we could have proved it without invoking matrices as operators concept, as long as one proves or gives justification for: product < min(rank of A and rank of B) , right ?

Comment: @subratverma: Yes, that’s right. I just found it easier to think in terms of the operators.

Answer (score 2):

For any given matrix, the dimension of it's row vectors is equal to the dimension of its column vectors. Therefore, since m>n, both matrices have rank at most 'n'.
The rank of a product of two matrices can be no bigger than the minimum rank of either matrices, since every matrix multiplication is a linear combination of rows/columns of either matrix. So the product is of rank at most 'n' but an m*m matrix is invertible iff it is of rank m